# Magento is looking for front end files in the install directory instead of pub/static/

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am at a loss on how to fix this. This is after an upgrade to 2.1.16, setup:upgrade , setup:di:compile, and static-content-deploy. I've also done cache clears and flushes.

[image]

[image]